# Lineintegral of absolute value with path $\gamma: [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C},t\mapsto i +\exp(i\pi t)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, line-integrals

Calculate:

$\int_{\gamma} |z|dz$ with $\gamma: [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C},t\mapsto i +\exp(i\pi t)$

I tried calculating it and actually made some progress, where one term vanished when splitting the integral in real and imaginary part, but the substitutions needed to arrive at the value afterwards just seem to complicated (I checked with Wolfram Alpha). Are there any tricks to bring to make this integral more managable ?

Comment: Well, the path is just the upper arc of a circle of radius $1$...Can you see it?

Comment: All you need is $2\sin (\pi t) \cos (\pi t)=\sin (2\pi t)$ and $2\sin^{2} (\pi t)=1-\cos (2\pi t)$. If you show your work you can get some help. I don't see any complicated expressions here.

Comment: I tought about that (wich would make the value be $1/2\cdot\pi r^{2}$ but is that a formal argument ? @DonAntonio

Comment: @Cristian **What** is a "formal argument"? It's just basic knowledge of complex numbers: $$i+e^{i\pi t}=\cos\pi t+i(\sin\pi t+1)$$ The above is a circle around $\;(0,1)\;$  of radius 1...but only the upper arc as $\;0\le t\le\pi\;$ ...

Comment: Well, I started off with using the definition of a line integral so I got $i\pi \int_{0}^{1}|i+\exp(i\pi t)|\cdot \exp(i\pi t) dt$ and using the definition of absolute value of a complex number I'm already stuck, I don't see how I could apply those trig identities here. @Kavi Rama Murthy

Answer (score 1):

Well, writing down using the definitions:
\begin{align}\int_\gamma |z|dz  & = i\pi\int_0^1|i+e^{i\pi t}|e^{i\pi t}dt \\& = i\pi\int_0^1 \left(cos(\pi t)^2+(1+\sin(\pi t))^2\right)^{1/2}(\cos(\pi t)+i\sin(\pi t))dt .\end{align}

Now, we compute the real and imaginary part of that integral in two separated integrals:

\begin{align} \int_0^1\left(cos(\pi t)^2+(1+\sin(\pi t))^2\right)^{1/2}\cos(\pi t)dt & =\int_0^1 \left(1-\sin^2(\pi t)+(1+\sin(\pi t))^2\right)^{1/2}\cos(\pi t)dt \\
& = \sqrt{2}\int_0^1 (1+\sin(\pi t))^{1/2}\cos(\pi t)dt \\ & = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3\pi}\left(1+\sin(\pi t)\right)^{3/2}\Bigr|_0^1 \\ & = 0\end{align}
since $\int (1+\sin(\pi t))^{1/2}\cos(\pi t)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int u^{1/2} du$ using $u=1+\sin(\pi t)$.

Now, the imaginary part: It's harder to calculate, but using several times chain rule, you will get: 
$$\int (1+\sin(\pi t))^{1/2}\sin(\pi t)=-\frac{\sqrt{\sin(\pi x)+1}(-4\sin^3(\frac{\pi x}{2})+3\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})+\cos(\frac{3\pi x}{2}))}{3\pi(\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})+\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2}))},$$
and replacing:
$$\int_0^1 (1+\sin(\pi t))^{1/2}\sin(\pi t)=\frac{8}{3\pi}.$$

So
$$\int_\gamma |z|dz= i\frac{8}{3\pi}.$$

Comment: Didn't you forget a square root when calculating the absolute value ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I'll correct now